# Application context gets killed but activity not

Tags: android, application-lifecycle

I'm working on an application which has a few Activities. One Activity starts the next one. To share some Values I'm using a custom implementation of Application (I'm talking about *android.app.Application*) called MyApplication.
As we all know, the Android system kills an app, if it needs more space. But this leads to a problem:

- I open my app and use it just like any other app
- I close it (Home Button) and use other apps
- The system will kill my application because it's wasting memory
- When I reopen my App, it wants to open the last activity I used and I get a force close, because the values in MyApplication are null

The strange thing is, that the system destroys my Application, but it seems like it keeps the Activity. I don't really understand why this is so because the Application doesn't seem to have a life cycle.

What I want to have:
When MyApplication (whole Application, not only the activity) gets killed, I want the last activities to be killed too. So when I reopen the App, it starts the main acitvity provided by the manifest.xml.
**or**
The values in MyApplication are persisted and don't get lost if the Application gets destroyed. (I'm talking about a few objects so i think the shared preferences won't work).
I don't want to use a service to bind my activities to, but is there a similar way to tell the system that my last used activity depends on the application-context?

I hope you understand what my problem is and someone can help me out with this.

Comment: I like how none of the answers seem to refer to your use of a custom Application even though you clearly note its use :/).

Have you tried utilizing Application.ActivityLifecycleCallbacks at all, not sure if that is what you are trying to accomplish even (seems like you might need the reverse directio ).

Comment: i think you are referring to **Activity Stack History**, rite?

Comment: Thanks MikeIsrael you're right. The answers below don't refer to my problem. Using the Activity Lifecycle is just a workaround. I'd prefer if the Application could handle its activities and kill them if the whole application gets killed.
Activity Stack History rather handles Backbutton-behaviour than my problem. I'm really sure this is an Application problem, not an Activity Problem.

Comment: @joshplusa Did you find a resolution for this? I now have exactly the same problem in that my `android.app.Application` contains lots of "global" data, and I am finding that sometimes on returning to the application that the activity stack still exists (so for instance I'm returned to an activity that relies on that global data) and yet the `.application` extension has been killed. This is confusing as I was under the impression that `.application` instance lasts for the lifetime of the task.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The right way to do things would be to save your application state.
Override the onSaveInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) method to save your state and onRestoreInstanceState to retrieve it.

If you need to save large sets of data consider using a SQL database

Comment: Thanks for the Tipp but as I wrote in my post, this doesn't works for me. As far as I understood it, I can't save my own Objects in the applications state.

Comment: Then my best guess would be to use a SQL database to save your objects

Comment: Alright. I'll take a closer look what's the beste way to solve my problem. Thank you for the help!

Answer (score 0):

You should make sure the app closes and restarts the way you want it to in the `onPause()` , `onResume()` and `onStop()` methods. Check out `savedInstanceState` which can save the state of the app (and restore it, when it's sent as a parameter to onCreate)

Comment: Thanks but I talking about Application not Activity.

Comment: @joshplusa You were talking about both, and you wanted the main activity to be started when resuming after onStops(), right?

Comment: Yes. At the moment I'm checking my values in onResume(). If they're null i finish the app. By doing this I'll get to the main activity anytime. But it's kind of dirty. Maybe I have to take a closer look an the Activity Stack History. Thank you for the response!

Answer (score 0):

In your custom implementation of Application,  add a Flag say :

```
public boolean appContextExist = false;
```

On your first Activity set the flag to true,

Override onCreate and onResume method on your Activity which need the contexts, add following :

```
MyApplication myApp = ((MyApplication) getApplicationContext());
if (!myApp.appContextExist) {
    // Code to return to start activity here
}
```